# Is there a lot of Plan 9 development?

Tags: operating-system, kernel, plan-9

It seems that the biggest contributors of Plan 9 are no longer in the project and it does not seem that there is a big development. There is 9fans, a mailing list for Plan 9 users, and once a year they usually do a meeting, but I have been surfing the source code and there's a lot of code from 2002-03, other from 2005-06 and a little from 2008-09 (http://plan9.bell-labs.com/sources/plan9/sys/src/).

I wanted to give it a try as a daily use OS (as I am an student and do not need anything serious right now) and I have no idea whether to use it or not because of the development it's going on.

Thank you. It would be great if someone who is up to date with Plan 9 could give me an answer.

Comment: Give it a try.  Just because there's no recent development doesn't mean that it doesn't work.  The biggest problem you'd run into is lack of support for the newest hardware.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm probably going to do, give it a try. Some legendary programmers, such as Ken Thompson or Rob Pike, are not longer there, and that's a big problem. I will probably set up Plan 9 in Virtual Box (which is supported, AFAIK).

Comment: Give it a shot. I have it running natively and have used it to surf the web and chat on IRC. It is *very* different to everything else out there.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have contacted with one of the organizers of the Plan 9 meeting and conferences and the development is active, although not with a lot of people, but it's interesting for sure.

[Here](http://code.google.com/p/nix-os/) it goes all the development of the system based on Plan 9. Programmers from Bell Labs, for what the person I contacted told me, are also involved in it, so check it out.

This mister also is the lead developer of [Plan B](http://lsub.org/ls/planb.html), a set of user programs which run on top of Plan 9 (and, I guess, of Nix-OS as well, which is based on Plan 9).

They have even ported it to the Nintendo DS, so if you are one of those that has a Nintendo DS in your home, I'm sure it would be really interesting to check out all the projects related with Plan 9. [Here](http://code.google.com/p/inferno-ds/) it is the Inferno OS for Nintendo DS (based on Plan 9) that runs on NDS. [InfernoOS](http://code.google.com/p/inferno-os/) is also a variant of Plan 9 and runs in any PC (it's not the same as the one I have just talked about. It's the one the Inferno OS NDS is based from).

Also, if you are in Linux, you can run it from Linux itself without a Virtual Machine. Just download the ISO of Plan 9 (or variants, like Nix-OS) and install [9vx](http://swtch.com/9vx/). More info, [here](http://code.google.com/p/nix-os/wiki/GettingStarted).

Hope this helps. If I find more information, I will for sure update this post. Sorry for the mess of information.

Comment: since you seem to know a little bit about this area, could I just get confirmation that the nix-os you were talking about was [this one here](https://code.google.com/p/nix-os/) and that that has nothing to do with [this new nix-os](http://nixos.org/nixos/) here? I think they're different it just seems weird that they have the same name.

Comment: @MikeH-R Hello, Mike! Sorry for answering slightly late. Yes, as far as I know, they are totally different projects. The one hosted on Github is based on the Linux kernel, while the one at Google Code, on Plan 9.

Answer (score 4):

https://code.google.com/p/plan9front/

http://www.9legacy.org/intro.html

http://swtch.com/plan9port/

http://cat-v.org/ : http://planet9.cat-v.org/

;)

Comment: Thank you for the links! The 9legacy link seems very interesting. Will take a look to it. Thank you again.

Answer (score 3):

Plan9 runs on everything from a [Raspberry Pi](http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=80&t=48391) to the [IBM Blue Gene supercomputer](http://doc.cat-v.org/plan_9/blue_gene/).  I have successfully run it on old PCs salvaged from the company's dumpster.

The Plan9 compiler suite is the foundation of Google's Go language. Of course it helps that some of the people who developed Unix, then Plan9 now work for Google.

I suspect that a lot of very smart folks are using Plan9.  Some of those projects are probably too critical to be given too much publicity.  Rather like Paul Graham using Common Lisp as the "secret sauce" for ViaWeb.